# rails show page not showing associated record in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have groups and they have members(links).

My show page for a group is mainly used to list the members.

This worked fine in rails 3

I upgraded to rails 4 and everything else works but the list of `@members` doesn't show and I don't see any error.  This is a regular `erb` page (I also, separately, have a page with content loaded through ajax that should list members and that is also broken, but I'm focusing on the erb page for now).

The log shows

```
Started GET "/groups/49" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-18 20:34:25 -0400
Processing by GroupsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"49"}
  Group Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE `groups`.`id` = 49 ORDER BY group_name
 LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` WHERE ('group_id')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` WHERE ('group_id')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` WHERE ('group_id')
  Rendered groups/show.html.haml within layouts/application (5.5ms)
```

The link is: `link_to 'Members', group`

The routes are:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :links # Enables group/:id/link/new
  collection do
    post 'order_links'
  end 
end
```

The groups controller has the following for show:

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @members = Link.where(:group_id, params[:id]).order(:position)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render xml: @group }
    format.json { render json: @members }    
  end
end
```

and the page has:

```
  %ul#sortable
    - @members.each do |loop|
      = content_tag_for :li, loop do
        - construct_hyperlink(loop.url_address, loop.alt_text)
        = sanitize @address_url
        \- #{h @new_link_alt_text}            &nbsp;&nbsp;#{link_to 'details', link_path(loop), {"title" => loop.alt_text}}            &nbsp;&nbsp;#{link_to 'edit', edit_link_path(loop), {"title" => loop.alt_text}}
```

That's a bit hard to read grant you, but rest assured it's been working in rails 3 for years in this app :)

Maybe the problem is about getting information from an associated model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `where` clause.  This:

```
Link.where(:group_id, params[:id]).order(:position)
```

Should become:

```
Link.where(group_id: params[:id]).order(:position)
```